# Bootstrap, How to center a div row on screen size <768

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, centering

I want to make the div centered in the screen sizes <768 but its not happening. I use media queries and it does not happen. I just want it centered that's all. It should happen on after resizing to col-sm screens

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="row  ">
        <div class="message">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="img/img6.png" width="75px" height="75px" class="img-responsive message-icons">
                Hope for Peace
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="img/img7.png" width="75px" height="75px" class="img-responsive message-icons">
                Save The Earth
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="img/img8.png" width="75px" height="75px" class="img-responsive message-icons">
                Build The Future
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="img/img9.png" width="75px" height="75px" class="img-responsive message-icons">
                Good For Kids
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
message{
            font-size: 1.4em;
            margin-top: 2%;
            top: 2%;
        }
        .message-icons{
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 2%;
        }

 .message{
            margin: 0 auto !important; 

            float: none !important;
        }
        .message-icons{
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 2%;
            width: 20%;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

col-md is to desktop or laptop, anywhere, then if u wish it center when is <768, is "xs" tan meaning you can use, col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1, so it center
look [CSS-Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/16qgbwp3/)

Key here is to `center` the text inside with `text-center` css class

I am hoping thats what your were looking for